# Biased Bernoulli random variable?

Tags: probability

I have an exercise where it says "For example, if $X$ and $Y$ are Bernoulli random variables with bias $\frac{1}{2}$(fair coin), then...". What does it mean that a fair coin is a coin with bias $\frac{1}{2}$? To me this doesn't make sense because I have learnt that bias is defined for some estimator $\tilde{\theta}$ to be: $\text{bias}(\tilde{\theta}) = E(\tilde{\theta}) - \theta$ where $\theta$ is the parameter being estimated.

I cannot relate this definition to why a Bernoulli random variable "with bias $\frac{1}{2}$" is automatically reflecting a fair coin. Can someone help me out?

Also, doesn't the use of "bias" depend on what we are trying to estimate? This also confuses me because it is not stated :/

Comment: I don’t study statistics, but since no one has answered you I will help you with my best guess. A Bernoulli random variable is anything that spits out one of two outcomes, independent of repeated trials. Excuse me for probably butchering the terminology, but the bias here is going to just be the probability of success. A fair coin has an equal chance of either flip, so the bias is $1/2$. Whether this sense of the word bias is anything to do with your formal estimation bias, I do not know.

Answer (score 2):

Here, read "bias" as simply "probability of success", "probability of heads", or "mean". You correctly observe that the term "bias" clashes with the bias of an estimator. Moreover, in academic works there appear to be two conventions to describe the "bias" of coins or Bernoulli random variables:

1. A "coin" or Bernoulli random variable with "bias" ranging in [-1/2, 1/2], with a "bias" of 0 being equivalent to a mean of 1/2. (Especially used in literature on random walks and martingales.)
2. A "coin" or Bernoulli random variable with "bias" ranging in [0, 1], with "bias" equal to mean. (Especially used in literature on "Bernoulli factories".)

Answer (score 1):

That is an odd term to use, they should have said “expected value” — you are correct that bias seems inappropriate here.